# Problem of optimization of a React-Redux-Reselect app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, lodash, reselect

I have only been using React and Redux for some months, and I have implemented Reselect recently in order to try and make the application faster. I can't get it to work the way I would like it to, and I'm not sure where the problem comes from.

I resumed the development of a Planning app for the dev department I work for. The main page can have a certain number of weeks, contained in a `Row`. Each day of the week is a Component, and in each `Day` Component, you may have a `TimePlanned` Component. There is one `Row` Component line per ticket affected to a developer, and there can be as many as 10 tickets per user, so...there are a lot of Components.

I implemented Reselect so that my many connected Components did not get re-rendered as often as they used to be with Redux alone.

I have a problem with the `Day` Component. I am trying to have them access the smallest amount of data possible, to prevent the other `Day` from re-rendering when they are not concerned about the change.

Here is what the data that I want to 'sort' might look like :

```
planifie:{
   tickets : {
     29859 : {
       ticketId : 29859,
       typeId : 1,
       projectId : 6,
       userId : 3;
       planifications : [549],
       comments : []
     }
   },
   planifications : {
      549 : {
         planId : 549,
         ticketId : 29859,
         planDate : "2019-05-16",
         planTime : 480,
         userId : 3
      },
      550 : {
         planId : 550,
         ticketId : 29859,
         planDate : "2019-05-16",
         planTime : 480,
         userId : 6
      }
   },
   users : {
      3 : {
       userId : 3,
       userName : "pdupont",
       tickets : [29859],
       comments : [],
       planifications : [549]
      }
   }
}
```

There are, of course, several records for each 'category'.

My selectors looks like this :

```
export const getAllPlans = state => state.planifie.planifications
export const getGroup = state =>  _.find(state.filters.plannedFilters.groupBy, ['isActive', true])
export const getUserPropsId = (state,props) => props.userId

export const makeGetAllPlans = () => {
    return createSelector(
        getAllPlans,
        plans => plans
    )
}

export const makeGetRelevantObjectPlans = () => {
    return createSelector(
        [getAllPlans,getGroup,getUserPropsId],
        (planifications,group,user) => {
            switch (group.code) {
                case 'project':
                    return _.filter(planifications, {projectId : user})
                case 'user':
                    return _.filter(planifications, {userId : user})
                case 'type':
                    return _.filter(planifications, {typeId : user})
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The `props.userId` is always a number, but if my planifications are sorted by projets, it will be equivalent to a projectId. The memoized selector's goal is to return the `planifications` object relevant to the Id passed in props.

For this example, my filter is by user. I would like a `Row` of my `Day` components to only get access to the planifications with a '3' userId.

In my `Day` Component, this is how I call the selector :

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
    const getComs = makeGetRelevantComments()
    const getPlans = makeGetRelevantPlans()
    const getPlanifications = makeGetRelevantObjectPlans()
    const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
        return {
            coms : getComs(state,props),
            plans : getPlans(state,props),
            planifications : getPlanifications(state,props)
        }
    }
    return mapStateToProps
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
    bindActionCreators(ActionsCreators, dispatch)
)

export default connect(makeMapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Day)
```

I put a function in my `componentDidUpdate()` to see what triggers re-renders, and on every `Day` Component, even the ones with a different props.userId, the `planifications` change, so my page takes very long to load.

For example, if I update the date of one planification with this Redux reducer action :

```
case types.SET_PLAN:
            return {
                ...state,
                planifie: {
                    ...state.planifie,
                    planifications : {
                        ...state.planifie.planifications,
                        [action.data.planId] : {

                 ...state.planifie.planifications[action.data.planId],
                            ...action.data.plan
                        }
                    }
                },
                isLoading: false
            }
```

Then every single one of my Day Component gets re-rendered.

I am wondering if I am missing something in my code, if I misunderstood what a memoized selectors can do, if the lodash `filter` function prevents is interfering with the immutability of the code, or if my data is not formated for this type of thing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran through your code and there very few things that might be helpful:

1.`getGroup` selector **must** be memoized, because after each update of store `_.find` will return new Array and memoization for `makeGetRelevantObjectPlans` will be broken.

So `getGroup` might look like:

```
const groupBy = state => state.filters.plannedFilters.groupBy;

const getGroup = createSelector(
  [groupBy],
  (groupBy) => _.find(groupBy, ['isActive', true]),
);
```

2. Using of [`createStructuredSelector`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createstructuredselectorinputselectors-selectorcreator--createselector) instead of `makeMapStateToProps` might also be helpful

Comment: Thank you ! This gives me hints at how to fix my problem. I will try your solutions as soon as I am able.